# Identify Cert in Soap request

Tags: certificate, x509, wsse

I am receiving a SOAP message that contains:
- wsse:BinarySecurityToken
- KeyInfo
etc.
The Problem is that there are multiple certs that corresponds to that in my truststore, i want to identify which Cert this SOAP REQUEST contains.
Sample Header:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 
        ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="X509-******************">
        **************</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ds:Signature Id="SIG-***************" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="mes soapenv touc" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#id-***************************">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="mes touc" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>**************=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>**************</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-**********************">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="STR-*******************" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-*********************" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1"/>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
```

Comment: ************** **************= ************** ?????

Comment: that's the id; i like to keep it that way.